# SQL - Get historic count of rows collected within a certain period by date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For many years I've been collecting data and I'm interested in knowing the historic counts of IDs that appeared in the last 30 days. The source looks like this

| id | dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2002-01-01 |
| 2 | 2002-01-01 |
| 3 | 2002-01-01 |
| ... | ... |
| 3 | 2023-01-10 |

If I wanted to know the historic count of ids that appeared in the last 30 days I would do something like this

```sql
with total_counter as (
select id, count(id) counts
    from source
    group by id
),
unique_obs as (
    select id
    from source
    where dates >= DATEADD(Day ,-30, current_date)
    group by id
)
select count(distinct(id))
from unique_obs
left join total_counter
on total_counter.id = unique_obs.id;
```

The problem is that this results would return a single result for today's count as provided by `current_date`.

I would like to see a table with such counts as if for example I had ran this analysis yesterday, and the day before and so on. So the expected result would be something like

| counts | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1235 | 2023-01-10 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-09 |
| 1265 | 2023-01-08 |
| ... | ... |
| 7383 | 2022-12-11 |

so for example, let's say that if the `current_date` was `2023-01-10`, my query would've returned `1235`.

Comment: Are you looking for a daywise count ? can you use this `select dates, count(ID) as counts 
    from source
    where dates >= DATEADD(Day ,-30, current_date)
    group by dates` ?

Comment: It's a daywise count of all the times IDs appear from the IDs that appeared in the last 30 days. My original query does this but it only reports one date. I need to run that query for ALL dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a distinct count of Ids from the 30 days up to and including each date the below should work

```sql
WITH CTE_DATES
AS
(
    --Create a list of anchor dates
    SELECT  DISTINCT
            dates
    FROM    source
)

SELECT       COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)   AS "counts"
            ,D.dates                AS "date"

FROM        CTE_DATES   D
LEFT JOIN   source      S ON S.dates BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-29,D.dates) AND D.dates --30 DAYS INCLUSIVE

GROUP BY    D.dates
ORDER BY    D.dates DESC
;
```

If the distinct count didnt matter you could likely simplify with a rolling sum, only hitting the source table once:

```sql
SELECT  S.dates     AS "date"
        ,COUNT(1)   AS "count_daily" 
        ,SUM("count_daily") OVER(ORDER BY S.dates DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 29 FOLLOWING) AS "count_rolling" --assumes there is at least one row for every day. 

FROM    source S

GROUP BY S.dates
ORDER BY S.dates DESC;
;
```

This wont work though if you have gaps in your list of dates as it'll just include the latest 30 days available. In which case the first example without distinct in the count will do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't do it. Imagine that I want to get the result for today. In that case I run the query in the OP. Now imagine I want to get the result for yesterday. In that case I change the parameter 'current_date' to yesterday's date, and so on. I want to do that for all dates in a single query.

Comment: This looks like it should do exactly what you're looking for... Unless you are saying that this skips over dates that aren't in your table so you wouldn't get a count for that date?

Comment: Wait. My bad. The query is 100% correct. Thanks my guy!

Comment: Glad you got it working bud :)

Comment: @MillosDavid if you're happy maybe mark as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) AS Counts
    dates AS Date
FROM source
WHERE dates >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY dates
ORDER BY dates DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't do it. It should return the same value for the current_date as the query from the OP shows.

Comment: I misunderstood the request apparently. Are you trying to accomplish this for every date in your table? Or just a certain date range?  Sounds like you'll want to use a numbers table and explode your desired date range and then join across it to get what you're after.